I am trying to copy/paste a named Excel range to another range in the same worksheet using Python xlwings
I am trying to copy a named range in Excel (ex. "Question_1") and paste it into an empty area of the same worksheet, using Python (xlwings). I am getting an attribute error which mentions "api". The last 1 or 2 lines of the code appear to be the problem.
The spreadsheet internally contains a set of multiple choice questions and each question draws on a set of incorrect responses and correct responses which are jumbled each time the spreadsheet refreshes. The Python code is to create a random selection of questions out of the total which will eventually reach 50.
I am using Spyder.
import xlwings as xw
mypath= "C:\\Users\\barry\\Desktop\\WS Generators\\MC Question Generator2.xlsm"
app= xw.App()
wb=app.books.open(mypath)
sheet = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

import random
randomnumber = random.randint(1,15)
randlist = []
randlist.append(randomnumber)

for i in range(5):
    randomnumber = random.randint(1,15)
    if randomnumber in randlist:
        continue
    else:
        randlist.append(random.randint(1,15))

j=0
question = "Question_"+str(randlist[j])
print(question)
sheet["question"].select
sheet["question"].copy("K2:M9")
sheet.range("K2:M9").paste(None,None,False,False)

The last block of code, starting with j = 0, is going to be a loop through the elements of randlist. First, I needed to tackle the copy/paste issue. I've searched all over but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

I believe it should be sheet[question], not sheet[“question”]. No double quote around variable name.

I removed the double quotes but still not working. I did notice in the worksheet that K2:M9 was selected but nothing in the cells. 'com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'PasteSpecial method of Range class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)'

I replaced 'sheet["question"].copy("K2:M9")' with 'sheet[question].copy(wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range('K2:M9'))' it pasted formulas and not values, so progress. Thank you for your input.

Adding wb.app.calculation = 'automatic' before sheet[question].copy(sheet.range('K2:M9')) should get the formula evaluated.

If you want to set a range of cells' values, you can just use range(...).value = range(...).value, which effectively is a copy and paste values.
